# What do the red paths mean in pocket planes?

Tags: pocket-planes

The paths that makes you know where the planes are going, that are usually green, some times be red. What does it mean?!

Answer (score 1):

Red paths indicate the path other planes is taking, while green paths indicate the path of your current plane.